# JOIN on Subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, subquery

I want to execute a simple join on two tables after connecting two columns with ids on one of these tables.

First step:

```
SELECT cars.hhid & cars.vmid
FROM cars
```

Now I want to compare this result with another table (table2).

The new result should be every row in table1 (cars) that match with id in table2.

What’s wrong?

My code:

```
SELECT Cars.* 
FROM (SELECT Cars.hhid & Cars.vmid AS zid
FROM cars) x
JOIN table2 ON table2.id = x.zid;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've said in the question, I don't see why you need a subquery at all.

Try this:

```
select cars.*
from cars 
inner join table2 on cstr(table2.id) = cars.hhid & cars.vmid
```

*(tested with* `double` *as data type for all three fields)*

You don't need the subquery because you can put your "connected columns" directly into the `JOIN` clause (of course you can put them into the `SELECT` clause as well if you need them there).

However, as soon as you concatenate the columns, Access seems to treat them as a `string`, so you can't join them directly on the `double` column in `table2`.
That's why you need to convert the column from table2 to a string with `CStr()`.

Comment: Hey Christian, thank you for your explanation. Your code does exactly what I want to do.

You guys here are great!

Comment: @Simon: If my answer was helpful to you, it would be nice if you would [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*** Answer for TSQL, prior to learning it was MS-Access ***

SQL has no `double` data type, so you'll need to use float.

To use the concatenation operator `+` the values will need to be converted to a string using `CAST` or `CONVERT`

Data:

```
declare @cars table (hhid float, vmid float)
declare @table2 table (id float)

insert @cars values (1,1),(2,2)
insert @table2 values (11),(22),(12),(21)
```

Query:

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(c.hhid AS nvarchar(20)) + CAST(c.vmid AS nvarchar(20)) AS zid
    FROM @cars c
    ) x
INNER JOIN @table2 t ON t.id = x.zid
```

*** Attempt at MS-Access ***

Does this work any better, to me it looks like your table references are slightly wring

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM (SELECT c.hhid & c.vmid AS zid
FROM cars c) x
JOIN table2 t ON t.id = x.zid;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer.
The data type for hhid, vmid (on table ‘cars’) and id (on table2) is double

Comment: Updated the answer for a double\float datatype

Comment: Iam using (german) MS-Access and it's responding with an error:

Unzulässige SQL-Anweisung; 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'SELECT', 'PROCEDURE', oder 'UPDATE' erwartet.

means: the SQL-Statement is incorrect, Access is looking for DELETE', 'INSERT', 'SELECT', 'PROCEDURE', or 'UPDATE'

Comment: Ah, Didn't know this was MS-Access. I don't think CAST/CONVERT is supported in that. Can you convert to a string using `Cstr`

Comment: I have changed the data typ to string. 
I think the cast is no longer needed. Isn't it?

Is there something else I can try?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an attempt at MS-Access, see if that helps

Comment: The MS_Access attempt leads to an syntax error on the FROM statement. What do you mean by "it looks like your table references are slightly wring". What can I do to adapt my table references?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM (SELECT Cars.hhid & Cars.vmid AS zid
FROM cars) x
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = x.zid;
```

MS Access like the join type to be specified.

Comment: thx 4 help. I tryed your query (with c as small letter type). Unfortunately still not working.

Comment: @Simon is table2.id a text field?